# How to center the content of a javafx 8 scrollpane

Tags: javafx-8

I have a ScrollPane, which contains a GridPane, which contains an ImageView, which contains an Image.  What I want is for the Image to be centered in the GridPane.

Without the ScrollPane I was able to accomplish this with setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER), however once I added the GridPane to the ScrollPane the Image was displayed in the upper-left corner.

How do I either get the ScrollPane to use the setAlignment() value or manually center the Image?

---example edit---

code without scrollpane:

```
public class ImageDB extends Application
{
  @Override
  public void start(Stage root)
  {
    Image image = new Image("0.jpg");
    ImageView view = new ImageView();
    view.setImage(image);

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.getChildren().add(view);

    grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
    border.setCenter(grid);

    root.setScene(new Scene(border));
    root.setMaximized(true);
    root.show();
  }
}
```

result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3tV6.png

code with scrollpane:

```
public class ImageDB extends Application
{
  @Override
  public void start(Stage root)
  {
    Image image = new Image("0.jpg");
    ImageView view = new ImageView();
    view.setImage(image);

    ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
    scroll.setContent(view);

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.getChildren().add(scroll);

    grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
    border.setCenter(scroll);

    root.setScene(new Scene(border));
    root.setMaximized(true);
    root.show();
  }
}
```

result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aQCb.png

Comment: Can you post some code? What else do you have in the `GridPane`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's happening is that while the grid pane is centering the scroll pane, the image view is sitting at the top left of the scroll pane.

One fix is to wrap the image view in a stack pane (which centers by default), and make sure the stack pane is at least as wide as the scroll pane's viewport:

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageDB extends Application
{
  @Override
  public void start(Stage root)
  {
//    Image image = new Image("0.jpg");
    Image image = createImage();
    ImageView view = new ImageView();
    view.setImage(image);
    StackPane imageHolder = new StackPane(view);

    ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
    scroll.setContent(imageHolder);

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();

    imageHolder.minWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> 
        scroll.getViewportBounds().getWidth(), scroll.viewportBoundsProperty()));
    grid.getChildren().add(imageHolder);

//    grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
    border.setCenter(scroll);

    root.setScene(new Scene(border));
    root.setMaximized(true);
    root.show();
  }

  private Image createImage() {
      return new Rectangle(400, 200, Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE).snapshot(null, null);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: That solves it, thanks.  One comment though: the minWidthProperty().bind() piece can be replaced with setMinWidth(scroll.getViewportBounds().getWidth())

Comment: That will break though if the user resizes the window, or if the grid pane changes size for another reason.

Answer (score 9):

While `imageHolder.minWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> scroll.getViewportBounds().getWidth(), scroll.viewportBoundsProperty()));` indeed does the trick, there seem to be some issues with it (e.g., sometimes showing erroneous scrollbars/flickering content, etc.).

I since found that a simple `scroll.setFitToWidth(true);` (and/or `scroll.setFitToHeight(true);`) also keeps the content sized with the scroll pane, but without the aforementioned issues!

Comment: the only issue with this is that setting fitToWidth for example means that the scroll view will not scroll horizantally

Comment: @joshLor what do you mean with "the scroll view will not scroll..."? For me the content of the scroll pane still scrolls when I use e.g. `scroll.setFitToWidth(true)`

Comment: It is interesting for me as I have a grid pane in my scroll pane and the grid pane is filled with labels. When it reaches the width then ellipses start to show rather than a scroll bar. Is there something else wrong with this approach that is messing it up. Note: without this piece of code it does scroll horizantally.

Comment: I also had the problem of `fitToWidth` effectively disabling the scroll feature. I had a `TableView` inside a `ScrollPane` and I solved it by 1- Wrapping my `ScrollPane` in an `HBox` and 2- Giving the `TableView` a `Min Width` and a `Min Height` **and leaving everything else on default** (`USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` and `ScrollPane`'s `ViewPort` properties all set to zero).

Answer (score 6):

This could help in some cases:

```
<ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" fitToHeight="true">
```

Comment: This is easy and correct answer for how to center content inside a scrollpane.

Answer (score 1):

Better solution via viewportBoundsProperty:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageDB extends Application {
    final static int WIDTH = 400;
    final static int HEIGHT = 200;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage root) {
        // Image image = new Image("0.jpg");
        Image image = this.createImage();
        ImageView view = new ImageView();
        view.setImage(image);
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.getChildren().add(view);

        ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
        scroll.setContent(grid);

        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        border.setCenter(scroll);

        this.center(scroll.getViewportBounds(), grid);
        scroll.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            this.center(newValue, grid);
        });

        root.setScene(new Scene(border));
        root.setMaximized(true);
        root.show();
    }

    private Image createImage() {
        return new Rectangle(ImageDB.WIDTH, ImageDB.HEIGHT, Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE).snapshot(null, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    private void center(Bounds viewPortBounds, Node centeredNode) {
        double width = viewPortBounds.getWidth();
        double height = viewPortBounds.getHeight();
        if (width > ImageDB.WIDTH) {
            centeredNode.setTranslateX((width - ImageDB.WIDTH) / 2);
        } else {
            centeredNode.setTranslateX(0);
        }
        if (height > ImageDB.HEIGHT) {
            centeredNode.setTranslateY((height - ImageDB.HEIGHT) / 2);
        } else {
            centeredNode.setTranslateY(0);
        }

    }

}
```