# JavaFX ScrollPane scroll beyond content

Tags: java, javafx

I have a game that is played in a 2D-world and I am currently working on the world editor. The editor draws the elements of the map as JavaFX Rectangles and Lines in a JavaFX `Group`. While the world can be infinitly big, the `Group`-node that I use to draw the map in shrinks to the minimal size required by the map.

To enable the user to pan through the map of the world, I wrapped the JavaFX Group in a `ScrollPane`. That actually works but the ScrollPane pulls the Group into its upper left corner like this:
[image: Everything is in the upper left corner]
That means that the user can scroll down or to the right if there are elements of the map below or on the right of the current viewport, but the user can only scroll up until the upper-left element of the map is in the upper left corner of the ScrollPane. That is actually useful for usual content (you don't want to scroll beyond the top of a web page or a menu) but I want the user to be able to scroll even beyond that even if there are no map elements (that's what I meant by an infinite drawing plane before doing the edit):
[image: what it should look like]
(quick and dirty photoshop)

I already tried to center the group using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687994/how-to-center-the-content-of-a-javafx-8-scrollpane) but it resulted in the shapes dancing around the center of the window when manipulating them.

**Edit:**

Made the question a bi´t clearer (hopefully ^^ )

Comment: Not quite clear what you mean: You are talking about a map size but also of an infinite drawing plane. What is it?

Comment: Hey @hotzst, sorry for not beeing clear about it. I guess I was still in my universe while writing the question :) I hope it is a bit clearer now.