# JavaFX GridPane fitting in the ScrollPane which uses not all available space of the BorderPane

Tags: java, matrix, javafx, scrollpane, gridpane

I have a scene similar to the one shown with the fxml code below (made with SceneBuilder):

`sample.fxml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="bpMain" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="600.0" minWidth="800.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <center>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
            <children>
                <HBox AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <children>
                        <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                            <children>
                                <BorderPane>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </BorderPane>
                                <BorderPane layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                    <top>
                                        <Label text="List 1:" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                            <BorderPane.margin>
                                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                            </BorderPane.margin>
                                        </Label>
                                    </top>
                                    <center>
                                        <ListView minHeight="500.0" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                            <padding>
                                                <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                            </padding>
                                        </ListView>
                                    </center>
                                </BorderPane>
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                        <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                            <right>
                                <VBox minWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                    <children>
                                        <BorderPane>
                                            <center>
                                                <ListView minWidth="150.0" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                                    <BorderPane.margin>
                                                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                                                    </BorderPane.margin>
                                                </ListView>
                                            </center>
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0" />
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                            <top>
                                                <VBox alignment="CENTER" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <Label text="List2:" />
                                                    </children>
                                                </VBox>
                                            </top>
                                        </BorderPane>
                                    </children>
                                </VBox>
                            </right>
                            <center>
                                <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                    <top>
                                        <Label text="Label" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                            <BorderPane.margin>
                                                <Insets bottom="15.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                            </BorderPane.margin>
                                        </Label>
                                    </top>
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                    <center>
                                        <BorderPane fx:id="matrixBorderPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
                                    </center>
                                    <bottom>
                                        <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                            <children>
                                                <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <Button fx:id="button5" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#show5matrix" text="5" />
                                          <Button fx:id="button15" layoutX="171.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#show15matrix" text="15" />
                                                    </children>
                                                </HBox>
                                            </children>
                                        </VBox>
                                    </bottom>
                                </BorderPane>
                            </center>
                        </BorderPane>
                    </children>
                </HBox>
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

I want to add a matrix to the `matrixBorderPane` which is represented by `TextFields` in the `GridPane`. The code added below works prefect for me when matrix is small (see it when `Button` with `5` clicked), but with bigger dimensions the values are not all visible (`Button` with `15`):

`Main.java`

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Matrix");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(750);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(550);
        primaryStage.show();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

`Controller.java`

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML public BorderPane matrixBorderPane;
    @FXML public Button button5;
    @FXML public Button button15;

    private ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @FXML
    public void show5matrix(ActionEvent e){
        showMatrix(5);
    }

    @FXML
    public void show15matrix(ActionEvent e) {
        showMatrix(15);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    private void showMatrix(int size) {

        GridPane matrixGrid = new GridPane();
        StackPane gridHolder = new StackPane(matrixGrid);
        scrollPane.setContent(gridHolder);

        matrixGrid.setMinHeight(30*size);
        matrixGrid.setMinWidth(30*size);
        matrixGrid.setMaxHeight(30*size);
        matrixGrid.setMaxWidth(50*size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {

                TextField tf = new TextField();
                Double value = 1.22;
                tf.setText(value.toString());
                tf.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                tf.setEditable(true);
                tf.setPrefHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
                tf.setPrefWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);

                GridPane.setRowIndex(tf, i);
                GridPane.setColumnIndex(tf, j);
                matrixGrid.getChildren().add(tf);
            }
        }

        //gridHolder.minWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() ->
                //scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth(), scrollPane.viewportBoundsProperty()));

        //gridHolder.minHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() ->
                //scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight(), scrollPane.viewportBoundsProperty()));

        //matrixBorderPane.setCenter(scrollPane);
        matrixBorderPane.setCenter(matrixGrid); //to comment
    }
}
```

Thus, I added a `scrollPane` to the `matrixBorderPane` and then my `GridPane` called `matrixGrid` was placed in the `scrollPane`. I read here: [How to center the content of a javafx 8 scrollpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687994/how-to-center-the-content-of-a-javafx-8-scrollpane) that `StackPane` might be helpful while positioning it in the centre, but it didn't work for me like I needed it to.

You can see results of changes by uncommenting the commented lines and commenting the line marked as `//to comment` in the `Controller.java` class.

What I want exactly is to make `scrollPane` activate only if matrix is too big to fit the dimensions of `matrixBorderPane`, and if it does, I want it to be placed in the very centre of `matrixBorderPane`.

So I just want my `matrixGrid` to be in the `scrollPane` and be positioned in the centre of `matrixBorderPane` all the time, no matter how big is the matrix, but if it's too big, let the `scrollPane` do its work. So I want it to look exactly like while running code with three commented lines when matrix is small and to look like after clicking `15` (the same code) when matrix is big, but within the `scrollPane`.

Comment: Did you try the StackPane like your link suggests?

Comment: Yes, I accidentally removed the code responsible for this from the class, now You can see what I did. It centres the GridPane, but what I want is the scrollPane not to fill the whole free space in the centre of BorderPane, just that much of it that is necessary.